# Error in buddypress when using wp_editor

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

Since none of plugin works with new wordpress and buddypress for rich text editor I have started to implement it myself manually directly into the theme.

After using wp_editor() I got the editor on my fourms and it is posting forums content well without issue. However when I am trying to edit forums post it is not loading any content into the text editor. I am using below code if anyone can help me.

```
$content = bp_the_topic_text();
    $args = array(
    'quicktags' => true,
   'editor_class' => 'frontend',
   'textarea_rows' => 5,
   'tabindex' => 1
    );
wp_editor( $content, 'topic_text', $args);
```

This doesnt load the forum post content just wonder. I have tested with the sting and just works fine it loads the string but not the actual content with the function. I dont know either this is the right function to get the content or not.

I am getting output like 
[image]

I want show content in inside of editor.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try this http://pastebin.com/uqxdXmt3  , if you got any content ?

Comment: @vs7 it returns null value

Comment: That set the content is not saved to BuddyPress so first try to find that reason

Comment: "sdad" coming from ?

Comment: bp_the_topic_text() return this value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bp_the_topic_text()` echoes the value. It's a wrapper for `bp_get_the_topic_text()`, which returns the value. So you should do this instead:

```
$content = bp_get_the_topic_text();
```